How to make VSCode display \r character
There are some files that contains \r (without \n followed), which is displayed as line break in VSCode. I want to inspect these \r that does not have \n followed. Is it a way to make it display?
Using "editor.renderWhitespace": "all", "editor.renderControlCharacters": true in settings doesn't work.

\r might be a problem since it takes two character spaces, but you'd think there would be a way to display ↵.

It doesn't look like there is a built-in way to display the various line endings,  See Possibility to display line endings in text area is still open after many years.
However, check out this extension: code-eol.  It should show your carriage return character.

Supports \n, \r\n, and \r returns

